# GRPC Permission Denied

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, grpc

I am building application in Asp Net Core web API with microservice architecture. I want to make request/response call from one microservice to another using gRPC.

the problem is that the following code works on localhost but I can't deploy it on AWS.

This is my code for gRPC Server:

**Proto file**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Infrastructure";

//package CompanyManagment;

service CompanyProtoService{
    rpc GetCompanyLogos(CompanyLogoRequest) returns (stream CompanyLogoResponse);
}


message CompanyLogoRequest {
    repeated string CompanyId = 1;
}

message CompanyLogoResponse {
    string Logo = 1;
}
```

**Proto Service**

```
public class CompanyService : CompanyProtoService.CompanyProtoServiceBase
{
    private readonly ICompanyRepository _companyRepository;
    public CompanyService(ICompanyRepository companyRepository) 
    {
        _companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    public override async Task GetCompanyLogos(CompanyLogoRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<CompanyLogoResponse> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        List<CompanyEntity> companies = await _companyRepository.GetCompanies();

        Dictionary<string, string> companyLogos = companies
            .GroupBy(company => company.Id.ToString())
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First().LogoUrl!);

        List<string> logos = request.CompanyId.ToList()
            .Select(companyId => companyLogos.TryGetValue(companyId, out string logo) ? logo : "DefaultLogo.webp")
            .ToList();

        foreach (var logo in logos) 
        {
            CompanyLogoResponse response = new() { Logo = logo};
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(response);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        ConfigurationManager configuration) 
    {

        services.AddGrpc();

        return services;
    }


var app = builder.Build();
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
    });

    app.UseExceptionHandler(HttpContextItemKeys.Error);

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseResponseCompression();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<CompanyService>();
    });

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
```

In project **csproj** I also have

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\Company.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now Client Side, this is my code of request.

```
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("URL HERE"); 

            var client = new CompanyProtoService.CompanyProtoServiceClient(channel);

            CompanyLogoRequest recommendedCompanyLogoRequest = new() { CompanyId = { recomended.Select(x => x.CompanyId.ToString()).ToList() } };

            using (var call = client.GetCompanyLogos(recommendedCompanyLogoRequest))
            {
                while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
                {
                    recomendedLogos.Add(call.ResponseStream.Current.Logo);
                }
```

My main problem when I test the code from local host everything works fine but when I deploy it on AWS and try to reach the gRPC server from client side with real URL it give me the error:

```
Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 403")'
```

I don't know what am I missing my DevOps told me that everything is correct in his side and the problem is in back-end. do you have any suggestions what can be problem?

I have tried everything googled it and can't find similar problem. also when I changed the real url to some random one, the error changed to "The gRPC server does not exists on this URL". so from that I guess that my URL is correct. but can't find the solution to give access to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had a very similar issue about a year ago (`PermissionDenied` error), and solved it by setting up TLS with valid certificates. Localhost worked fine, in our network it only worked after setting up encryption. I think you need some special configuration to **NOT** use encryption with gRPC.

[Here it says in the Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client): *The ASP.NET Core gRPC template and samples use TLS by default.* and: *When an HTTP/2 endpoint is configured without TLS, the endpoint's ListenOptions.Protocols must be set to HttpProtocols.Http2. HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2 can't be used because TLS is required to negotiate HTTP/2. Without TLS, all connections to the endpoint default to HTTP/1.1, and gRPC calls fail.* Also checkout this Github issue: [gRPC doesn't work without HTTPS](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/505). It mentions that gRPC uses https per default, an that you need to switch it off if you don't want to use encryption, with the following line on the client-side:

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
```

The same code snippet is also mentioned in the Microsoft Documentation in the article [Call insecure gRPC services with .NET Core client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client). Other option of course would be to use HTTPS and set up encryption with valid certificates. Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Maybe you can configure the Kestrel on the server side to not use HTTP2 and TLS, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints.md) is a good documentation on how to configure the Kestrel, f.e.:

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
{
    int port = 5001; // your port here
    opt.ListenAnyIP(port, listenOptions =>
    {
        // configure Kestrel for HTTP2, not the default HTTPS2 (depends if you want to use HTTP1 or HTTP2)
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
    });
});
```

Also checkout this [github repon issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/919) on configuring the Kestrel with HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added that switch which you provided but I get the same error. I have also added 

builder.Services
    .AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(o =>
    {
        o.Address = new Uri("My Domain");
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
            HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

        return handler;
    });

same error.

Comment: also I found some configuration about kestrel that I have to add it to appsetting,json but I can't find how to do that, do you know some documentation about that?

Comment: The `appsettings.json` file can be found in the service project, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configureiconfiguration) is some documentation on how to modify it. But modifying the appsettings is just one way to modify the Kestrel, another is to modify the Kestrel via `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel` in the `Program.cs` file, as described in the same article.

Comment: Sorry to hear that my fix didn't work, maybe you also have to modify the server that hosts the services (-> the Kestrel) to allow unencrypted gRPC communication on both sides and make it work. As I said, I got rid of the `PermissionDenied` error in our network by setting up valid encryption for gRPC with TLS.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a comment on how I configured the Kestrel, maybe you can configure it in a similar way.